# How do I calculate my blaster's damage?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

I've noticed that the weapons in Battlefront do a lot of damage at close quarters, but the damage reduces with distance. Is there a formula for this? And if so, is it the same for all weapons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Symthic](http://symthic.com/battlefront-ttk-btk-charts) has all you need to know about what needs to be calculated in regards to figuring out the damage of the blasters.

There is a formula posted on the [Symthic Forums](http://forum.symthic.com/battlefield-4-technical-discussion/7532-formula-for-working-out-a-weapon-s-damage-at-range/), which I have confirmed, that will calculate the damage based off of the blasters max/min damage, max/min range, and firing range. The formula itself will exceed the max/min blaster damage, although that is handle within the game itself

> Damage = MaxDmg - (Range - StartFalloff) / (EndFalloff - StartFalloff) * (MaxDmg-MinDmg)

**Example Calculations**

[T-21B](http://symthic.com/battlefront-weapon-info?w=T-21B)

> Range = 19m
> Damage = 45 - (19 - 10) / (50 - 10) * (45 - 34)
> Damage = 42.525
>
> Range = 16m
> Damage = 45 - (16 - 10) / (50 - 10) * (45 - 34)
> Damage = 35.1

[DH-17](http://symthic.com/battlefront-weapon-info?w=DH-17)

> Range = 29m
> Damage = 25 - (29 - 25) / (40 - 25) * (25 - 5)
> Damage = 19.667
>
> Range = 38m
> Damage = 25 - (38 - 25) / (40 - 25) * (25 - 5)
> Damage = 7.667

Comment: thanks, but it still doesn't give a reason for the T-21 being so obnoxious.

Comment: @Parzival I agree, the T-21 is a very annoying gun to come across.

Comment: yeah, I always get killed by enemies with one health. Its my most used gun though, I have like 500 kills with heavy blasters because of it.